# Using .html with JQuery not posting all items in an array to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using an Ajax call to post some template data to my HTML view with JQuery.

However, when I feed arrays to the following function, it only prints out one of the items in the array in the HTML/view.

The Ajax call:

```
request = $.ajax({ 
              url: "/fans/follow", 
              type: "post", success:function(data){

                var results = data;
                $.each(results, function( index, value ) { 

                    var template = '<li>'
                   +'<div class="row-fluid">'
                   +'<article class="span3">'
                   +'<a href="/fans/"'+value.fan_tag+'>'
                   +'<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/'+value.fbid+'/picture" alt="" height="40" width="40">'
                   +'</a>'
                   +'</article>'
                   +'<article class="span9 userDescp">'
                   +'<span>'
                   +'<a href="/fans/"'+value.fan_tag+'>'
                   +value.first_name+' '+value.last_name
                   +'</a>'
                   +'</span>'
                   +'</article>'
                   +'</div>'
                   +'</li>';

                   $('div#new_content').find('ul').html(template);

                });

              }, 
              data: {'id': id} ,beforeSend: function(data){
                console.log(data);
              } 
            });
```

The HTML where it is supposed to print the template:

```
<div id="new_content">
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Looking in the console, the array is being returned by ajax correctly, but it is not print all of the items, only the first one.  I have also checked and the .each loop is going around as many times as there are items in the array, so that's not the issue.  Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is because you are overwriting the content in a loop

```
request = $.ajax({
    url: "/fans/follow",
    type: "post",
    success: function (data) {

        var results = data,
            //cache a reference and emtpy the ul
            $ul = $('#new_content').find('ul').empty();
        $.each(results, function (index, value) {

            var template = '<li>' + '<div class="row-fluid">' + '<article class="span3">' + '<a href="/fans/"' + value.fan_tag + '>' + '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + value.fbid + '/picture" alt="" height="40" width="40">' + '</a>' + '</article>' + '<article class="span9 userDescp">' + '<span>' + '<a href="/fans/"' + value.fan_tag + '>' + value.first_name + ' ' + value.last_name + '</a>' + '</span>' + '</article>' + '</div>' + '</li>';

            //add the template to the existing contents instead of overwriting it
            $ul.append(template);

        });

    },
    data: {
        'id': id
    },
    beforeSend: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: so just replace ".html" with ".append"?

Comment: @user1072337...you have to do that..use append

Comment: @user1072337 also you might want to empty the `ul` before the loop